# Can I convert unorganized point cloud data to organized point cloud data using PCL in C++?

Tags: c++, point-cloud-library, point-clouds, pcl

I want to convert unorganized point cloud data to organized point cloud data using PCL in C++. I want to have normal estimation of point clouds. But the code accepts organized point cloud data. Do you have any suggestions?

https://pcl.readthedocs.io/projects/tutorials/en/latest/normal_estimation_using_integral_images.html#normal-estimation-using-integral-images

Comment: Hi! Welcome to stackoverflow. Your question is very vague. What does your point cloud look like and what do you want it to look like instead?

Comment: Also see Mark Loyman's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53364350/17613754).

Answer (score 0):

Generally no. Organized point clouds are similar to images, meaning that points have a neighbour relationship. See here for more information: https://pcl.readthedocs.io/projects/tutorials/en/master/basic_structures.html#basic-structures

The tutorial you posted only works with organized point clouds, but this one also works with unorganized point clouds: https://pcl.readthedocs.io/projects/tutorials/en/master/normal_estimation.html#normal-estimation